# An explanation with Cocos2D method

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I just started with cocos2D and came across something that looks like this ..

```
CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:13];
```

then I can just simply do stuff with the object.

I'm really curious with what's happening after the ' = ' part of the code.

I know that the [self getChildByTag:13] retrieves the object by the tag  I assigned to it in a previous method, the -(id)init method, and I know that by it self (CCSprite *) is just a pointer to something that will be a member of it self.. but how do these two things work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are fetching a `CCSprite` object in a scene by requesting the "child" via tag.

The `getChildByTag` method retrieves the node (or `CCSprite` in this case... you may want to put in a bit of validation code to make sure what's retrieved truly is a `CCSprite` object) and then assigns it to your `sprite` variable (thanks to a cast you're doing in there).

Oh, [here's a related question that might help you out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668664/cocos2d-using-getchildbytag-from-child-classes-to-get-objects-in-a-scene), too.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I have a follow-up question for you. 

Since I am aware that we're never truly sure that the returned object is what we might expect, the book is teaching me to use NSAssert and another method, which are fine. 

My question to you is, could I just ignore that all together and simply do (id) instead of (CCSprite *) or using defensive coding measures?Would using 'id' solve that problem?

Comment: **NO**.  `id` type is the Objective C equivalent of `void *`.  There's no type checking involved in there so if the object retrieved via `getChildByTag` isn't the `CCSprite` you're expecting, you are likely to run into a crash.  Best to do some validation on that object (including an assert).